System hang error step build net core with jenkins pipeline on ubuntu?
I try deploy system net core on vps ubuntu  , but  system hang .Info of vps : ram 1 gb , cpu 1 core , ssd 21gb .
System hang step dotnet build .
Script pipeline
pipeline
agent any
stages {
    stage('Cloning Git') {
         steps {
            checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/main']], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: '.....................', url: 'https://.........@gitlab.com/../......']]])
        }
    }
     stage('Build Stage') {
        steps {
            echo 'start build'
            sh """
            cd FacilityManagementWebClient
            dotnet build -c Release /p:Version=1
            dotnet publish -c Release --no-build
            """
            echo 'end build'
        }
    }
}

log error of job :
wrapper script does not seem to be touching the log file in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Deploy-Pipeline@tmp/durable-f29751e5

 (JENKINS-48300: if on an extremely laggy filesystem, consider - 
Dorg.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask. 
BourneShellScript.HEARTBEAT_CHECK_INTERVAL=86400)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code -1
Finished: FAILURE

Detail enviroment :
Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Net Core 8.0

Thanks you so much.

There's not nearly enough information here.  [Edit] your question with the error message as text, and what you've tried so far (i.e., what you've found when entering that bug in your favorite search engine).  Include your job configuration as well so this will contain a [mcve].

Also, please post the error text and not a picture of text.
